# Clojure: use vector within an atom?

Tags: clojure, atomic

I have created an atom, that contains a vector:

`(def name-seq (atom ["A" 1]))`

Within the `swap!` operation, I need to increment the number that's the last part of the vector. Here's what I am trying:

`(swap! name-seq #(["A" (inc (last @%))]))`

I get the following error: `ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Future  clojure.core/deref-future (core.clj:2108)`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That worked - so, `swap!` sends the `deref`-ed atom to the given function. Thanks!

Comment: weird. I added a comment and SO removed the original comment from @loki. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @loki for the answer via a comment. The `swap!` function sends the deref-ed atom to the swapping function. Hence I needed to remove the deref that I was doing with `@` from my solution:

`(swap! name-seq #(["A" (inc (last %))]))`.

Comment: The error from my first approach is still unintuitive though.

Answer (score 1):

If your `name-seq` is a fixed-length vector, then you may use [`update-in` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in) to do so:

```
(swap! name-seq #(update-in % [1] inc))
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that I was deref-ing inside the swap fn, but this is a great & succinct answer.